# Smart Target 2014 installation issue

Tags: 2013, smarttarget

I am installing smart target 2014. As per SDL live content, during installation of Smart Target on content delivery it is required to copy smarttarget_conf.xml from Tridion config folder, to the config folder of Odata service.

I have checked for smarttarget_conf.xml file in config folder of my CMS installed path. It is not available. Can anyone suggest if I have missed any step.

Is smarttarget_conf.xml placed in config folder during CMS installation?

Thanks.
Mukesh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, the installation package contains some sample configuration xml files.

For smarttarget, you can find it here in your installer package :
Content Delivery\configuration\samples\smarttarget_conf_sample.xml.

You should put that file in your odata config directory, rename it, and make the necessary adjustments for your environment.

Answer (score 6):

The Content Delivery installer will place a copy of the sample file into the config folder (either under your website or in the installation directory, depending on what technology you've chosen).

It is also available under the installation folder, in the Content Delivery\configuration subfolder. Don't forget to remove "_sample" from the filename if you decide to copy it from there.

Comment: Thanks all, my smart target installation had not put the smart target config file. I got it from installation media.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are following the [Installing SmartTarget Web service instructions](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-C46FC390-C929-418D-9B11-AB052EF3CF0E) from the manual. That one mentions `Go to your Content Delivery %TRIDION_HOME%\config directory and copy the smarttarget_conf.xml file to the classes or config subdirectory of your Web application.`. The installer will place the `smarttarget_conf.xml` in the TridionHome/config but you can also copy it from the installation media in `SmartTarget 2014\Content Delivery\configuration\samples`.

In any case, try to align the `smarttarget_conf.xml` across your web applications, just like you would do for the cd_storage_conf.xml. This will make the maintenance of the configurations a lot easier. The following applications are using the `smarttarget_conf.xml`:

- SmartTarget web service / Content Delivery web service (the one you are looking at)
- CD deployer
- Presentation server / your website webapp